# How to I remove the indent caused on either side of each blog post?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, blogs, tumblr

I am using Tumlbr and wish remove an indent made either side of each post. I would prefer to have the blog posts width to be 100%. Thanks in advance. The url to the website which I am editing is http://jarroldtheme.tumblr.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{title}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
    {block:Description}
        <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
    {/block:Description}
    <style>
    header h1 {
        color: {TitleColor};
        font-family: {TitleFont};
        font-weight: {TitleFontWeight};
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 35px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
    }
    header p {
        color: black;
        font-family: helvetica;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    header a {
        color: {TitleColor};
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .page {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    .page a {
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
    body {
        background: {BackgroundColor};
        font-family: helvetica;
    }
    .post {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 45px;
        padding-bottom: 45px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .link-post {
        background: #000;
    }
    .like-reblog {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .like-reblog li {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px;
  }
    .quote-source {
        padding:20px;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    form {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .sfm input {background-color: #f5f5f5; 
    font-size: 9px;
    border: 0px; 
    text-transform: lowercase; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
    color: #999; 
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;}
    input[type="submit"] {
      background: #900000;
      color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    {block:haspages}
    <div class="page">
        {block:pages}
        <a href="{URL}">{Label}</a>
        {/block:pages}
    </div>
    {/block:haspages}
    <h1><a href="{BlogURL}">{title}</a></h1>
    {block:Description}
    <p>{Description}</p>
    {/block:Description}
    <form action="/search" method="get" class="sfm">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}" id="sf"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="sb"/>
</form>
</header>
 <ol>
            {block:Posts}{block:Text}
            <div class="post">
                    <li>
                        {block:Title}
                            <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                        {/block:Title}{Body}
                    </li>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Text}{block:Photo}
                <div class="post">
                    <li>
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>

                        {block:Caption}
                            {Caption}
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Photo}{block:Panorama}
                <div class="post">
                    <li>
                        {LinkOpenTag}
                            <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                        {LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}
                            {Caption}
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Panorama}{block:Photoset}
                <div class="post">
                    <li>
                        {Photoset-500}{block:Caption}
                            {Caption}
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Photoset}{block:Quote}
                <div class="post">
                    <li>
                        "{Quote}"
                        {block:Source}
                            <div class="quote-source">{Source}</div>
                        {/block:Source}
                    </li>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Quote}{block:Link}
                <div class="post">
                <div class="link-post">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>

                        {block:Description}
                            {Description}
                        {/block:Description}
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Link}{block:Chat}
                <div class="post">
                    <li>
                        {block:Title}
                            <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                        {/block:Title}

                        <ul>
                            {block:Lines}
                                <li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
                                    {block:Label}
                                        <span>{Label}</span>
                                    {/block:Label}{Line}
                                </li>
                            {/block:Lines}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Chat}{block:Video}
                <div class="post">
                    <li>
                        {Video-500}{block:Caption}
                            {Caption}
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Video}{block:Audio}
                <div class="post">
                    <li>
                        {AudioEmbed}{block:Caption}
                            {Caption}
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </li>
                    <ul class="like-reblog">
            <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li><li>{likebutton}</li><li>{reblogbutton}</li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Audio}
                {/block:Posts}
        </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is that you are trying to get the elements with the post ID to move all the way to each side you can try by setting the padding of the ordered list to 0. Checked it using Chrome dev tools.

```
`ol{padding: 0;}`
```

I would also recommend using a css reset to remove the browser default styles like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). They really help out a ton

Edit: To move the black box all the way over, you can set the margin of the body to 0 on both the left and right:

```
body{margin:auto 0;}
```

a CSS reset could help you avoid doing all this ^.^

Comment: Thank you so much that has helped massively, however the back box is still not touching each side of the screen. @peyssoa

Comment: Thanks you have completely solved my problem. You are a hero @peyssoa